# Is it possible to link SVN repository files so that a file is actually a reference to another repository's file?

Tags: svn

I can see some potential difficulties with this concept but the idea is:

I change a file in Repository A and commit, Repository B has a file that is a link to a file in Repository A, I click update on the file in my working copy for repository B, and i receive the updated file from repository A.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Yes, for directories anyway

See [this section on svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html). The `svn:externals` property is set on a versioned directory; its value is typically another versioned directory in a repository (possibly the same one) of your organization. They act in the end something like symbolic links.

Update: Good call also by [basszero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287/basszero) but note that the questioner almost certainly does not have an svn 1.6 repo, so he can't do it with files.

Comment: This should work for all the files in that directory.  I am using something like this here.

Comment: subversion 1.6 support externals defintions for files as well

Comment: @basszero: svn supports only file externals to text files, binary files cannot be "externalized"

Comment: thanks for additional info, I did not know the text file limit

Comment: One question, what entails a 1.6 repo? Is all that's needed that the server-side runs Subversion 1.6 or higher, or does the format have to be converted in some way also?

Answer (score 25):

If you're lucky enough to use [subversion 1.6](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html), you can have [external links](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) for both directories **AND files**

Comment: "lucky enoug", lol as if only the rich kids can afford to get thier hands on this little gem of free open sourcedness.

Comment: If he's not hosting the repo himself, he probably doesn't have control over what version is on the server. Free doesn't always mean accessible :)

Comment: svn1.6 supports only file externals to textfiles.

Comment: you've never maintained legacy code or worked for the government. Sometimes I'm happy to use ANY version of subversion.

Comment: No need for legacy code or government. In the company I'm currently working we still use svn 1.6.18 because porting would be "to expensive ergo unnecessary"...

Answer (score 11):

Check out this post..
It helped me
[how to properly set svn svn externals property in svn command line](http://beerpla.net/2009/06/20/how-to-properly-set-svn-svnexternals-property-in-svn-command-line/)

For those who dont want to follow the link here is a brief overview.

```
svn propset svn:externals 'akismet http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/akismet/trunk' .
```

- **akismet** - dir or file name you want your link to be called
- **http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/akismet/trunk** - The link to the svn repo you want to link to
- **.** - The current directory so make sure your in the dir you want the link to reside

After running the above do a

```
svn commit
```

and

```
svn update
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do with "external" links in your subversion repository.

Personally I find this is very useful for incorporating open source libraries into my code (Codeplex, Google Code, etc...).

Search for "svn:externals" to find documentation on the details

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which will synchronize all the files.
Use `ln` command to create a **hardlink** and then copy that in all the folders. The method is described below (**Linux**).

1. `$ ln source_file.txt ~/desired_directory/first_copy.txt` This will create a hard link of source_file.txt and put a copy in desired_directory.
2. Repeat the same process to produce multiple copies of the same file (actually it's simply linking of file) and put it in the any directory you like.
3. Update the source_file.txt and it will update all other linked files as well.

Cheers.

For Windows, one may use `mklink` to link files.