# Copying file from one project to another in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I'm working on a multi-module project. We're using the appCtx.xml from one module in few other modules.

Current issue is that they're not always in sync with each other.

It happens when someone modifies the file and the project builds, the person doing that can forget to copy to another module and it causes issues.

How do I copy appCtx.xml inside src/main/resources from project A to src/main/resources in project B?

Comment: Can you add a direct dependence?

Comment: Another idea is to use your revision control system to help.  I don't know if you use SVN but see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401951/is-it-possible-to-link-svn-repository-files-so-that-a-file-is-actually-a-referen

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do this with the [maven resources plugin: copy-resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html), something like:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-appCtx</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/src/blahhere</outputDirectory>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>../other_project/src/blah/blah</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>appCtx.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This copies a file from one project (colocated on the same source tree) as part of the generate-resources phase. You can adapt this to your needs.

This copying from one project to another may cause unstable builds if the projects aren't all built at once, but the above will work for projects which are always built together.

Comment: Do I get this right that the path ```../other_project/src/blah/blah``` assumes that both projects are currently stored locally on my disk? How would I do this if the source project is not cloned locally but the resource should be taken from a snapshot in the artifactory?

Comment: @BenjaminZach did you manage to solve this? I have some files in a “commons” jar, and this jar is included in other projects. How do i copy files from within the commons jar into other projects?

Answer (score 0):

Another, perhaps more updated way, is to use `maven-dependency-plugin` with `unpack` goal and `fileMappers` to rename the destination of the unpacked files.

This official documentation with an example helped me a lot: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-filemapper.html