# how to include file from one module to another module in multi module maven project

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a maven project which is multi module project , I want to include the file from moduleA/src/main/bin/abc.sh to other module say moduleB which already has its structure like moduleB/src/main/bin/pqr.sh 
on building the project the structure of module is like moduleB/bin/..*.sh 
How do I include abc.sh in moduleB 
I have tried using maven-resources-plugin as

```
  <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-cleanup</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${multi.module.project.root.dir}/modules/abc/src/main/bin</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>abc.sh</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

which give me error on building the project as

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (copy-cleanup) on project moduleB: /bin/abc.sh (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: It seems that the user who launches the script doesn't have enough rights. What if you run sudo chmod 777 -R at the project's root?

Comment: It simply does not make sense to copy file to `/bin/` where you have of course no permissions. And also you shouldn't do that during a maven build...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386543/copying-file-from-one-project-to-another-in-maven

Answer (score 0):

If you're really working in `/bin` directory of your machine, you should be aware that to work in this directory on UNIX you need `root` account.

Also, I recommand **TO NOT WORK WITH `ROOT` ACCOUNT** on your machine in this case.

I recommand instead to grant `read` access the user you're currently using to package your application.

**Command :**

```
sudo chmod o+r /bin/abc.sh
```