# Selective SVN export of files in a repository

Tags: svn, export

I have been on this problem for a few days now and have not been able to solve it.

I'm not sure if my method is the feasible so if anyone has a better workaround I'm open for ideas so I'm  going to offer the whole picture

This is the scenario

We have a large repository which we are currently moving from StarTeam to SVN.

within the repository we have a specific directory holding a set of *linked* files. These are files linked to their original files distributed throughout the rest of the project tree. We use the files in this directory to generate the stings needed for translation.

In SVN there is no linked feature. I need to have the option to be able to export only the files related to translation of the latest revision but only those files not the entire revision problem begin they are distributed around the repository. In total there are about 300 of these files so its not possible to manually

I was also though of maybe using properties to set all the files but there is no way to export via properties

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to do this with svn and not external scripting (which you should consider as an alternative), you probably need to create a new repository structure for this.

One feature of svn is svn:externals where you can build a new repository that will fetch subdirectories from other svn repositories. As you say you have so many files, I think some kind of external scripting may be the only reasonable solution.

I would probably go with something like this: I would put a list of files to a text file that is in the repository and have a script take that list of files and export it where you need it in the structure you need it. The list format and the tools to process depends on the structure you have and the one you need to export.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.  I will not require the version history.  I just need to be able to pull out this particulate set of files every time we have a new release. In starTeam there is a feature to have linked files which basically means I have the same file in two locations but when one of them update I can identify that it has changed by looking at its link. Unfortunately restructuring repository is not an option

Comment: Looks like svn:externals can also do files. StackOverflow: [is it possible to link SVN repository files...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401951/is-it-possible-to-link-svn-repository-files-so-that-a-file-is-actually-a-referen) and [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) help.

Comment: You might be able to use the svn properties (like externals but others) to tag the files you want to export and make your tool export the files based on that information. I don't know if there are ready-made solutions available.

Comment: @Jonxm05 - if original files are distributed over *different places* in repo, you can use svn:externals, but have to use fresh version of SVN, there svn:externals can contain not only directories, but also **singe files** (it's 1.6 or 1.7, can't recall). Beware, files-externals have some not-obvious things - read fresh SVNBook about externals

Answer (score 0):

This is not a SVN-based solution but a workaround for your problem based on SVN constrains.

Not sure if it would work, but you may consider changing the layout of your repo just reversing direction of the translation file links. You may keep the actual files within your directoy, say the one you want to export, and use links where the actual files were located formerly ("*distributed throughout the rest of the project tree*").

There you wouldn't have problems with SVN to export the translation files directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by *links*. Subversion on Unix can store symbolic links to other files in the repository, but I usually don't recommend it. It's not Windows friendly.

How do you use these *links* exactly? Do you export just this directory, and since it is linked to the actual content, you pull out only the files you want? Are these like file system links, or is this a proprietary feature of StarTeam like the old *share* in VisualSourceSafe?

I usually recommend taking care of something like this via a build system of some sort. You could use a build language like Ant which is quite powerful and works on any platform that uses Java. Or, you could use something like Python or Perl. I would stay away from shell scripts and Batch scripts since they're not quite as universal.

You do a full check out from your repository, and then run the build to do the export for you. The export will simply copy the desired files into a build directory of some sort. (I recommend to create a directory called `target` under the root of the checkout and put all build generated files under there. It makes cleaning up a build very straight forward. I'd put the generated *build* under `target/archive`).

This not only makes it easier to move from version control system to version control system, but will allow you to use a system like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to create and store the needed artifacts. When you need a release, instead of checking it out, you can simply download it from the Jenkins webpage.