# Issues using svn:externals

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I want to link directories in SVN as shown in this post: [Is it possible to link SVN repository files so that a file is actually a reference to another repository's file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401951/is-it-possible-to-link-svn-repository-files-so-that-a-file-is-actually-a-referen) however I seem to be doing something wrong. Here is what I am doing:

```
cd $HOME
mkdir svn
mkdir svn_checkout

svnadmin create svn/test
cd svn_checkout
svn co file:///$HOME/svn/test
cd test
echo 'Hello world!' > hello_world.txt
svn add hello_world.txt
svn commit -m "added first file."
cd $HOME

svnadmin create svn/test2
cd svn_checkout
svn co file:///$HOME/svn/test2
cd test2
svn propset svn:externals 'test file:///$HOME/svn/test' .
svn commit -m "added externals."
svn update
```

When I run update I get this:

```
Updating '.':
svn: warning: W200000: Error handling externals definition for 'test':
svn: warning: W180001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///$HOME/svn/test' At revision 1.
svn: E205011: Failure occurred processing one or more externals definitions
```

Does anyone know how to fix my issue? Oh and if it matters here is my version number.

```
svn --version
svn, version 1.8.10 (r1615264)
```

Comment: Does the error really have `$HOME` in it (or did you do that to protect your privacy)?  If so, then that's your problem; the path can't have any shell variables in it.

Comment: Thank you this was my problem. I replaced $HOME/svn/test with the full path to my svn test repo and it worked without any issues.

Comment: **You can not use file-externals for cross-repository linking**